# Referencing multiple elements in function using 'this' - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, event-delegation

Take this function:

```
$(document).on('change', '#ele1, #ele2', function() {
    if (this.value == "") {
        $('.link').bind('click', false);
    } else {
        $('.link').unbind('click', false);
    }
});
```

How would I reference the elements `#ele1` and `#ele2` separately using `this`?

Comment: You can pass the event and use `e.target`

Comment: @elclanrs can you put an example please

Comment: What is it you're ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: @LeeTaylor I want an easy way to check if the values of `ele1` and `ele2` are empty - it's for validation.

Comment: `this` refers to the currently changed element - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/08dqo0um/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny So what you're saying is i am actually already doing that?

Comment: @Edward yes you are!!! - what is the problem you are facing

Comment: Back to the drawing board then.

Comment: I am trying to disable a link based on if either of these two inputs are empty any neat ideas? - need it to trigger if either one is changed.

Answer (score 0):

As ArunPJohny pointed out `this` references the currently changed element only, so instead i just referenced them directly.

```
$(document).on('change', '#group_name, #dept-name-input', function() {
    if ( $('#group_name').val() == "" || $('#dept-name-input').val() == "") {
        $('.add-td').bind('click', false);
    } else {
        $('.add-td').unbind('click', false);
    }
});
```